# Why do I get a CS1061 error for a button in my asp.net c# web forms application for a button?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I get the following error in my production environment, but not when I run this on my localhost:

> CS1061: 'ASP.frm_new_doc_rvw_aspx' does not contain a definition for
>   'btn_send_email_notification_Click' and no extension method
>   'btn_send_email_notification_Click' accepting a first argument of type
>   'ASP.frm_new_doc_rvw_aspx' could be found (are you missing a using
>   directive or an assembly reference?)

Button:

```
<asp:Button ID="btn_send_email_notification" runat="server" Text="Send" OnClick="btn_send_email_notification_Click" />
```

Code behind:

```
protected void btn_send_email_notification_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MailMessage msg = new MailMessage();
        msg.From = new MailAddress("myemail@gmail.com");
        msg.To.Add(new MailAddress(email_recipient_txt.Text));
        msg.Subject = "A document has been submitted for your review";
        msg.Body = "A review for document number " + email_doc_id_pk_txt.Text + " " + "titled " + email_doc_title_txt.Text + " " + "for vendor " + email_vendor_nm_txt.Text + " " + "has been submitted for your review.  Reference review number" + " " + doc_rvw_id_fk_txt.Text + " " + "submission number" + " " + email_doc_sub_id_txt.Text;
        msg.IsBodyHtml = true;

        SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();
        smtp.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
        System.Net.NetworkCredential NetworkCred = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("myemail@gmail.com", "mypwd");
        smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
        smtp.Credentials = NetworkCred;
        smtp.Port = 587;
        smtp.EnableSsl = true;
        smtp.Send(msg);

        if (IsPostBack)
        {
            email_doc_id_pk_txt.Text = "";
            email_doc_title_txt.Text = "";
            email_vendor_nm_txt.Text = "";
            email_recipient_txt.Text = "";
            doc_rvw_id_fk_txt.Text = "";
            email_doc_sub_id_txt.Text = "";
        }
    }
```

I have tried deleting all of it and re-entering the code, including using a new button.  Since it works as expected on my localhost, but not on my production server (this is an intranet application), I ensured that I moved all three files (aspx, cs and designer) to the server.  I also updated the global.asax and it's cs file as well.

I would really appreciate any help.

I am using Visual Studio 2013, and this is an asp.net 4.5.1 web forms application using c#.

Comment: Is your DLL deployed on the server? You could try to make the click event handler public instead of protected

Comment: I would guess you deployed only the aspx page (code front?), and not the "code behind" .cs file that would get compiled into your applications dll

Comment: note that in a production deployment situation, you would (or should not) be deploying .cs files.  .cs files get compiled into a dll file kept in the bin folder for use in the application

Comment: @Kritner Actually, if it's a Web Site Project, then you would be deploying the .cs files. It's not clear whether this is a Web Site Project or a Web Application Project.

Comment: oh... sorry i don't think i've worked with that project type before

Comment: check the AutoEventWireup property on your page tag.. make sure it's true

Comment: It is a web application project.  I just moved the cs and designer files over because I was trying anything at this point.  I updated the bin folder on the web server, but I still get the same error.  I tried using public instead of protected, and I get the same error.

Comment: The AutoEventWireup is true.

Comment: I just added a formview and sqldatasource to another existing page in the application and I get the same error for the edit button.  So I created a new page and added a button to populate an asp:TextBox, and I get the same error.  Does this help at all?

Answer (score 0):

I didn't make any changes, but all of the buttons began working.  I no longer get the cs1061 error.  I still don't know what caused the issue.  I appreciate all of the help.